# Python Values in Lists

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.0 to write a program. In this program I deal a lot with lists which I haven't used very much in Python.

I am trying to write several if statements about these lists, and I would like to know how to look at just a specific value in the list. I also would like to be informed of how one would find the placement of a value in the list and input that in an if statement.

Here is some code to better explain that:

```
count = list.count(1)
if count > 1
    (This is where I would like to have it look at where the 1 is that the count is finding)
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would strongly suggest reading through a beginner’s tutorial on lists and other data structures in Python: I would recommend starting with [Chapter 3 of Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/index.html), which goes through the native data structures in a good amount of detail.

To find the position of an item in a list, you have two main options, both using the `index` method. First off, checking beforehand:

```
numbers = [2, 3, 17, 1, 42]
if 1 in numbers:
    index = numbers.index(1)
    # Do something interesting
```

Your other option is to catch the `ValueError` thrown by `index`:

```
numbers = [2, 3, 17, 1, 42]
try:
    index = numbers.index(1)
except ValueError:
    # The number isn't here
    pass
else:
    # Do something interesting
```

One word of caution: avoid naming your lists `list`: quite aside from not being very informative, it’ll shadow Python’s native definition of `list` as a type, and probably cause you some very painful headaches later on.

Comment: Thanks for these ideas. I have tried using the index method before but after reading in the documentation about how it would only look at the first x in the list I decided it couldn't be used for this instance. Although here it seems you have shown how it could be used with that number. Also, I don't actually use list as my list name I just did that for the example. Another thing, the comment for the second example that says "# The number isn't here" how would that actually be written in Python? Thanks again!

Comment: I think you must have misread the documentation: I have not heard anywhere about the `index` method only looking at the first *x* items in a list, and would consider that a critical bug in any Python implementation.

Comment: As for the comment, if written as a comment it would be written exactly as it appears. If you mean “how would you express it in code”, that’s entirely dependent on context: the `pass` statement simply means “do nothing”, which makes the two examples behave in the same way.

Comment: This is copied from the documentation: "array.index(x)
Return the smallest i such that i is the index of the first occurrence of x in the array."

Comment: I mean how would you express in Python: "The number isn't there."

Answer (score 4):

Check out the documentation on [sequence types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) and [list methods](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

To look at a specific element in the list you use its index:

```
>>> x = [4, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
>>> x[3]
0
```

To find the index of a specific value, use `list.index()`:

```
>>> x.index(1)
2
```

Some more information about exactly what you are trying to do would be helpful, but it might be helpful to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to get the indices of all elements you are interested in, for example:

```
>>> [i for i, v in enumerate(x) if v == 1]
[2, 4]
```

You could then do something like this:

```
ones = [i for i, v in enumerate(your_list) if v == 1]
if len(ones) > 1:
    # each element in ones is an index in your_list where the value is 1
```

Also, naming a variable `list` is a bad idea because it conflicts with the built-in list type.

**edit:** In your example you use `your_list.count(1) > 1`, this will only be true if there are two or more occurrences of `1` in the list.  If you just want to see if `1` is in the list you should use `1 in your_list` instead of using `list.count()`.

You can use `list.index()` to find elements in the list besides the first one, but you would need to take a slice of the list starting from one element after the previous match, for example:

```
your_list = [4, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
i = -1
while True:
    try:
        i = your_list[i+1:].index(1) + i + 1
        print("Found 1 at index", i)
    except ValueError:
        break
```

This should give the following output:

```
Found 1 at index 2
Found 1 at index 4
```

Comment: I think your example is misleading, it might lead one to believe `x[1]` is the same thing as `x.index(1)`

Comment: OK so that is excellent but could I do it from a list.count? Do you know if it is even possible to have it find the one that it is looking at and not just the first one as in list.index?

Comment: Following PEP 8 `if ones:` is preferred over `if len(ones) > 1`.

Comment: @cbbcbail - What do you mean by "the one that it is looking at", do you want to find the last occurrence of a value in the list?  `list.count` will be the total number of occurrences, but it doesn't give you any information on where in the list those values were.

Comment: @RobWouters - `if ones:` would be true if there is one or more in the list, `if len(ones) > 1` is only true if there are two or more.

Comment: I am sorry but the only thing I could find to use was list.count which I now see really doesn't help me at all here. FatBusinessman gave me a much better approach to this station. What I did mean is that if there is a count and it does find a 1 then I would like to know the position of that 1. But this wouldn't work at all if there were multiple ones which may happen in my program.

Comment: @cbbcbail - See my edit, it shows you how you can use `list.index()` to find subsequent elements in the list.  I definitely think it would be cleaner for you to use a list comprehension to get a list of all of the indices though.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.index(x)
```

Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

--

In the docs you can find some more useful functions on lists: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

--

Added suggestion after your comment: Perhaps this is more helpful:

```
for idx, value in enumerate(your_list):
    # `idx` will contain the index of the item and `value` will contain the value at index `idx`
```

Comment: I have viewed this very page in the docs and saw list.index(). But in my program it needs to be able to move onto the next one if it can't do something and this would keep it at the first "x" for ever if that "x" couldn't be changed.

Comment: Perhaps i you read my lengthy comment to the fat business man it will shed a little more light on what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out in which index is the element like this:

```
idx = lst.index(1)
```

And then access the element like this:

```
e = lst[idx]
```

If what you want is the *next* element:

```
n = lst[idx+1]
```

Now, you have to be careful - what happens if the element is not in the list? a way to handle that case would be:

```
try:
    idx = lst.index(1)
    n = lst[idx+1]
except ValueError:
    # do something if the element is not in the list
    pass
```